# Can I pool controllers in a spring mvc application and if so how will it effect the performance?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In spring 3.0 controllers can be created simply by annotating the class as @Controller and is singleton by default.

So to cater many requests container will have only one object of that type.

On the other-hand if it is prototype,then many objects will be created and hence resource utilization will be poor.

Please correct me if I am wrong. My question is can I pool the controllers and if I can, then will it improve the concurrency and throughput?

Comment: Why not just use singleton scope? That is a pool of 1

Comment: @samlewis That is one thing I need answers. I need to cater as many requests per second as possible. My problem is if I use a pool of many, then will it enhance throughput and if it does enhance, then does spring support it?

Comment: Spring MVC does not prevent multiple threads running through a singleton scoped controller concurrently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that all Controllers are singleton by default.

Unless your Controller is stateful there is no need to have a pool of instances. Your web container will be using a managed pool of Threads to handle requests, each of which can access the Controller at the same time (due to there being no shared state). I would suggest that tuning your web container will give you better results for concurrency and throughput.

If your Controllers are stateful then there is still no need for a pool of instances. Instead you should probably manage the state within [Session](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-session) or [Request](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-request) scoped beans and rely on Spring to inject these into the Controller on each request ensuring that multiple Threads of execution do not interfere with one another.

Given your current level of understanding you should be fairly comfortable with different scopes. I would suggest also reading and understanding how Spring makes use of [Proxys](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) to inject scoped beans into Controllers.